# Android Room Kotlin Database

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-room

How to open closed database room kotlin database android

I tried start and close app lots of times , I tried to open it from icon and nothing happens, I tried to use queries nothing happens so i really do not know what to do

The `@Dao` annotated interface:-

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertUser(user: User)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteUser(user: User)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM User")
   suspend fun gellAllUsers(): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE email LIKE :email AND password LIKE :password")
    fun readAllData(email: String, password: String): User

    @Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = :email AND password= :password)")
    suspend fun isUserExist(email: String, password: String ): Boolean
}
```

The `@Database` annotated abstract class

```
@Database(entities = [User::class,Meal::class,Wishlist::class], version = 2)
abstract class UserDataBase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun mealDao(): MealDao

    abstract fun userWithMealsDao(): UserwithMealsDao

    abstract fun userDao():UserDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE:UserDataBase?= null

        fun getInstance(context: Context):UserDataBase{

            Log.d("TAG", "getInstance: I got this far")
            return INSTANCE?: synchronized(this){
                INSTANCE?: Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    UserDataBase::class.java,
                    "Userdata"
                ).build()
                    .also {
                   INSTANCE= it
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Rodina, please show the code/queries that you are working with e.g. dao interface and db instantiation or the repository

Comment: interface UserDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertUser(user: User)
    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteUser(user: User)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM User")
   suspend fun gellAllUsers(): List<User>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE email LIKE :email AND password LIKE :password")
    fun readAllData(email: String, password: String): User
    @Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = :email AND password= :password)")
    suspend fun isUserExist(email: String, password: String ): Boolean
}

Comment: Please Edit and add the code to your question for easy readability

Comment: I made it .....

Comment: Hi Rodina, have looked at it but unable to see where the problem is without the repo/viewmodel code where you calling the db functions. Pls see if you can add these to the question. I see you are also using Log Statements - are you getting any errors or exceptions from `Log.d()`?